# Python's mock.patch not patching class in unittest

Tags: python, mocking

I'm getting confused by using Mock in my python unittests. I've made this simplified version of my problem:

I have this dummy class and methods:

```
# app/project.py

class MyClass(object):

    def method_a(self):
        print(FetcherA)
        results = FetcherA()
```

Which is using this class:

```
# app/fetch.py

class FetcherA(object):
    pass
```

And then this test:

```
# app/tests/test.py

from mock import patch
from django.test import TestCase
from ..project import MyClass

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @patch('app.fetch.FetcherA')
    def test_method_a(self, test_class):
        MyClass().method_a()
        test_class.assert_called_once_with()
```

I would expect that running this test would pass and that `print` statement, for debugging, would output something like `<MagicMock name=...>`. Instead it prints out `<class 'app.fetch.FetcherA'>` and I get:

```
AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

Why isn't `FetcherA` being patched?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, fourth time through I think I understood the ['Where to patch'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) section of the Mock docs.

So, instead of:

```
    @patch('app.fetch.FetcherA')
```

I should use:

```
    @patch('app.project.FetcherA')
```

Because we're testing the code in `app.project.MyClass` where `FetcherA` has been imported already. So at that point `FetcherA` is availably globally(?) within `app.project`.

Comment: The reference to [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) just saved me. Thanks!! It had the same effect when I was trying to mock a function that was defined in a separate file outside a class.

Comment: Wow this is totally unobvious, especially at the module level. I have other classes where the full patch seems to work, and I wondered if this somehow was a related issue, and your answer here saved me a ton of head banging! Thank you!

Comment: I know SO frowns on "me too!" responses, but WOW @Phil you saved me a huge amount of time, this is quite counter-intuitive!